# dp:serialize and escaping on ibm datapower

Tags: xml, xslt, serialization, encode, ibm-datapower

I have a project where I need to binary-64-encode an xml-file and put it into another xml. To get this to work I first serialize the xml with `dp:serialize` and then use `dp:binary-encode` on the resultning variable from that. This works fine except for that all scandinavian characters are escaped. `åäö` gets to be `&#229;&#228;&#246;` when I decode the result.

Any ideas? I've tried with `dp:escaping="minimum"` on the output-tag (Does the `xsl:output` tag affect `dp:serialize`?)  and a number of other options. Through printing the serialized result before binary-64-encoding it I've seen that the escaping is added when `dp:serialize` is invoked.

Is it possible to serialize without escaping on datapower?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can serialize without escaping. The DataPower escaping, e.g. "disable-output-escaping" only affects the OUTPUT context and not the "inline" XML...

I think you must handle it as binary data and get the "untouched" XML file from /object/message/node().

Since the binary node is not "xml" you can encode it straight off:

```
<xsl:variable name="xmlInBase64" select="dp:binary-encode(/object/message/node())"/>
```